# Camel MessageID are different route transformation flow

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp, camel-sql

In my camel application, I am trying to send a message from the source AMQ Queue (INLET) doing some TRANSFORMATION(XMLTO JSON) to Target AMQ Queue (OUTLET) The message is successfully transferred from INLET to OUTLET. But the 1st Messages ID is different and the remaining all are the same in the entire route flow.

Below is the Message-IDs :

1. Message ID :ID:dbf0f290-c7e2-11ec-b776-6eb51c0a3021:-1:-1:-1:-1 **(DIFFERENT)**
2. Message ID :queue_INLET_ID_dbf0f290-c7e2-11ec-b776-6eb51c0a3021_-1_-1_-1_-1 **(SAME)**
3. Message ID :queue_INLET_ID_dbf0f290-c7e2-11ec-b776-6eb51c0a3021_-1_-1_-1_-1  **(SAME)**
4. Message ID :queue_INLET_ID_dbf0f290-c7e2-11ec-b776-6eb51c0a3021_-1_-1_-1_-1   **(SAME)**

Anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I used **exchange.getIn().getMessageId()**

After using this **exchange.getExchangeId()  //Solved my issue**